# Grab data from strings in R using regular expression

Tags: regex, r

Now the string is looks like:

```
"Interest.USD,Vol=[Integrated,(0,0.101),(0.2,0.108),(1,0.110),(2,0.106),
(3,0.102),(4,0.09),(5,0.091),(6,0.09128272)],Drift=[Integrated,(0.002,0.09),
(0.24,0.0007),(0.4,0.007),(1,-0.033),(2,-0.005),(3,-0.0041),
(4,-0.3505),(5,-0.65),(7,-0.08346),(8,-0.049),(9,-0.0613),(10,-0.019)],
Risk_Neutral=YES,Lambda=0.09,FX_Volatility=0.01,FX_Correlation=0.9"
```

I want to grab the data following the "Vol" and "Drift" in a matrix format like:

Vol matrix:

```
0,0.101
0.2,0.108
1,0.110
2,0.106
3,0.102
4,0.09
5,0.091
6,0.09128272
```

and also the single value like 0.09 for Lambda. I guess I shuold use regular expression, but I not that familiar with that. Any suggestion? :)

P.S.
I tried using:

```
str_extract_all(text,'[ .+? ]')
```

try to get the data bewteen [ and ], but it returns "."

Comment: You should use regular expression. Have you tried learning how to use them?

Comment: @SeñorO hi, thank you for comment. I edited my question with the way I have tried. Any suggestion for the code is welcome :)

Comment: why you didn't mention `2,0.106` in your output?

Comment: is there any newline exists in your input string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry..It was a mistake.. No new line exists in my input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to extract those values in R. Let's assume that strings you posted is stored in a variable named `a`. In order to make things easier, i'm going to use a helper function: [getcapturedmatches()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321). Then you can do

```
expr <- "(Vol|Drift)=\\[Integrated,([^\\]]*)\\]"
mm <- regcapturedmatches(a,gregexpr(expr,a, perl=T))[[1]]
expr <- "\\(([^,]+),([^,]+)\\)"
vv <- regcapturedmatches(mm[,2],gregexpr(expr,mm[,2], perl=T))
```

First we do a pass to extract the Vol and Drift elements in `mm` and then we split the comma delimited lists into `vv`. Now we can combine the data into one large data.frame

```
tt <- Map(data.frame, col=mm[,1], val=lapply(vv, 
    function(x) {class(x)<-"numeric"; x}))
dd<-do.call(rbind, unname(tt))
```

In the end `dd` will look like

```
     col  val.1       val.2
1    Vol  0.000  0.10100000
2    Vol  0.200  0.10800000
3    Vol  1.000  0.11000000
4    Vol  2.000  0.10600000
5    Vol  3.000  0.10200000
6    Vol  4.000  0.09000000
7    Vol  5.000  0.09100000
8    Vol  6.000  0.09128272
9  Drift  0.002  0.09000000
10 Drift  0.240  0.00070000
11 Drift  0.400  0.00700000
12 Drift  1.000 -0.03300000
13 Drift  2.000 -0.00500000
14 Drift  3.000 -0.00410000
15 Drift  4.000 -0.35050000
16 Drift  5.000 -0.65000000
17 Drift  7.000 -0.08346000
18 Drift  8.000 -0.04900000
19 Drift  9.000 -0.06130000
20 Drift 10.000 -0.01900000
```

This method allows for any number of repeated values in each of those sections.

If you did just want simple matrices then

```
Map(function(a,b) {class(b)<-"numeric"; b}, mm[,1], 
    lapply(vv, function(x) {class(x)<-"numeric"; x}))
```

will give you a named list of the matrices.

Comment: @Louisyan if you find this answer as a good one then don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this regex. The value inside brackets are stored into seperate groups and the stored groups are again referenced through backreference.

```
Vol=.*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*\(([\d,.]+)\).*(?=,Drift)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cU3dC0)

See the stored group on the right-side.